# How do I install xulrunner 1.9.2 for crashplan?

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, xulrunner, crashplan

I need to install xulrunner 1.9.2 for crashplan.

"Error I get is package is unabailabe but referred to by another package"

What repository do I need to add to be able to install this?

Answer (score 3):

You can download directly from here: 
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/amd64/xulrunner-1.9.2/1.9.2.17+build3+nobinonly-0ubuntu1
Regards

Comment: what if my machine has i386 architecture?

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/i386/xulrunner-1.9.2/1.9.2.17+build3+nobinonly-0ubuntu1